# Integrating of Piecewise PDF

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

**Question:** Find $P(Z>z)$ for the two cases $0 \le z \le 1$ and $z>1$.

**My attempt:** I have found a PDF of $f_Z(z)=1-\frac{1}{e^z}$ for $0\le z \le 1$ and $f_Z(z)=e^{1-z}-\frac{1}{e^z}$ for $z>1$ (and $f_Z(z)=0$ otherwise). I know $P(Z>z)=1-P(Z\le z)$ so I can integrate the PDF to find the $P(Z\le z)$.

However, I am unsure over what bounds to integrate these to find $P(Z>z)$ for each case. I know that, for each, one of the bounds will be $z$ but don't know how to determine this. For example, to find $P(Z>z)$ for the case of $0 \le z \le 1$, do I evaluate $1-\int_z^1 1-\frac{1}{e^z} dz$ or do I evaluate $1-\int_0^z 1-\frac{1}{e^z} dz$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** If anyone knows of any good online resources that explain how to determine the bounds of piecewise PDF integration, please comment them.

Comment: In general $$P(X \in A) = \int_A f_X(x)dx$$.
You have $P(Z>z) = P(Z\in(z,\infty))$

Comment: It is bad practice to use the same variable found in the bounds as the integration variable. @Viv4660

Answer (score 1):

You have $$f_Z(s)=\begin{cases}1-\mathrm e^{-s}&:& 0\leqslant s\leqslant 1\\[1ex]\mathrm e^{1-s}-\mathrm e^{-s}&:& 1< s\\[1ex]0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then $$F_Z(z)=\begin{cases}0&:& z<0\\[1ex]\displaystyle\int_0^z (1-\mathrm e^{-s})\mathrm d s&:&0\leqslant z\lt 1\\[1ex]\displaystyle\int_0^1(1-\mathrm e^{-s})\mathrm d s+\int_1^z(\mathrm e^{1-s}-\mathrm e^{-s})\mathrm d s&:& 1\leqslant z\end{cases}$$

So
$$1-F_Z(z)=\begin{cases}1&:& z<0\\[1ex]\displaystyle1-\int_0^z (1-\mathrm e^{-s})\mathrm d s&:&0\leqslant z\lt 1\\[1ex]\displaystyle \int_z^\infty(\mathrm e^{1-s}-\mathrm e^{-s})\mathrm d s&:& 1\leqslant z\end{cases}$$

Comment: When going from the PDF to the CDF, why did the bounds change for the case of $z=1$?

Comment: Style choice.  A proper CDF is right continuous so preferably should be written a format that reflects that.  Regardless, $F_Z(1)=\int_0^1(1-\mathrm e^{-s})\,\mathrm d s$

Comment: If I wanted to express the CDF with the pieces $z<0$, $0 \le z \le 1$ and $z>1$ as in the PDF, I would still have the same integrals for each section of $F_Z(z)$, wouldn't I?